# playing multiple audio / video files simultaneously with python-vlc

Tags: python, libvlc, python-vlc

I'm developing a tkinter application where video's and sounds are queued and played back based on certain events.

For this I use python-vlc, but I haven't found a way to play multiple sounds at the same time (besides multithreading). The videos would also need their own window for this to work.

the following code is from a module pure for testing this.

```py
import vlc

files = ['/home/silver/Desktop/hl1sfx/sound/gman/gman_potential.wav', 
         '/home/silver/Desktop/hl1sfx/sound/gman/gman_nasty.wav',
         '/home/silver/Desktop/hl1sfx/sound/gman/gman_nowork.wav',
         '/home/silver/Downloads/atlas_motor_jitter.mp4']



instance = vlc.Instance ()
medias = [instance.media_new (f) for f in files]
player = vlc.MediaPlayer ()

for m in medias:
    input ('>> ')
    player.set_media (m)
    player.play ()
    if player.is_playing ():
        p = vlc.MediaPlayer (m)
        p.play ()
    input ('next?')
```

Even creating a new mediaplayer doesn't work. Is seperate threads for each file the solution or am I overlooking some feature in python-vlc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can but you'll need separate instances.
Here is a simple and rather ragged way of doing it using lists. I'm sure you can devise a cleaner method, with time.

```
import vlc
import time

files = ['./V2.mp4','./vp1.mp3','./V3.mp4'] 
instances = []
medias = []
players = []


for idx, fname in enumerate(files):
    print("Loading",fname)
    instances.append(vlc.Instance())
    medias.append(instances[idx].media_new(fname))

    players.append(vlc.MediaPlayer())
    players[idx].set_media(medias[idx])
    players[idx].play() 

player_count = players # copy of the players list so we don't modify during iteration
still_playing = True
time.sleep(0.5) # Wait for players to start

while still_playing:
    time.sleep(1)
    for p in players:
        if p.is_playing():
            continue
        else:
            player_count.remove(p)
            players = player_count # no point iterating over players that have finished
            print("Finished - Still playing ", str(len(player_count)))

    if len(player_count) != 0:
        continue
    else:
        still_playing = False
```

p.s. to the moderator who removed my comment about the quality of another answer to this question. Do you condone "read the manual" type answers or comments? Shame on you. With that attitude this site will go to the dogs.
I await your `surreptitious` edit.

Answer (score 0):

Do this with mpyg321:

```
pip3 install mpyg321
from mpyg321.mpyg321 import MPyg321Player
```

Then:

```
while True:
    player = MPyg321Player()
    player.play_song(input('Path To Song'))
```

Thanks

Comment: this wouldn't work with video files right? I need a solution which does both.

Comment: yes . this is for .mp3 file only . check out my second solution with Thereading

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use python-vlc

you can use 'Thread' and play music or ... in the background.

```
import threading

def MusicPlay(Name):
    #Your Code

while True:
    threading.Thread(target=Delete, args=('NameOfMusic',)).start()
```

Comment: if you are happy with the answer , I will be grateful if you vote .

Comment: could you explain your code a bit more? I don't really understand what this code is supposed to be doing

Comment: i think it would be better if you read about threading system and how it works